# Error connecting to an FTPS server using openssl s_client

Tags: openssl, ftps

I'm running this:

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect user:passwd@192.168.1.1:21 -CAfile demoCA/cacert.pem
```

and I get the following error:

> s_client: -connect argument or target parameter malformed or ambiguous`

Answer (score 2):

To connect to an FTP/S server you need to tell the openssl command about it:

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.1:21 -CAfile demoCA/cacert.pem -starttls ftp
```

This will establish the SSL connection and you will then be responsible for continuing the session directly

```
user remoteuser
pass theirpassword
```

The tool is not an FTP/S client so you will probably find that it's not terribly useful much past here unless you are able to set up the secondary data connections manually (not something I'd recommend at all). You might prefer `curl`,

```
curl ftps://remotehost:21/
```

Comment: More exactly, an 'explicit' (FTPES) server; for (rare) implicit (FTPIS) on 990 you don't use `-starttls`.

Comment: I understand the difference but I've never before come across the labels FTPIS and FTPES. In that terminology my FTP/S would be your FTPES. However, my preference would to ban the FTP protocol regardless of its transport and push people down the HTTPS or SFTP routes. FTP is a pain

Answer (score -1):

`openssl s_client` is a basic command which opens a simple connection to a server and it doesn't know about any protocols including HTTP or FTP.

What you trying to do however is to make this command to

- Know the FTP protocol (it does **not**)
- Authenticate using the FTP protocol (it **cannot**)

Please use a full featured FTPS client instead. Even if you somehow manage to authenticate manually (here's [an example](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/ftp-using-raw-commands-and-telnet/) ), you won't be able to transfer files because FTP normally uses two connection channels/streams and doing so from the console is extremely complicated.

You could use:

- FileZilla
- CrossFTP
- `lftp`
- or even `curl`